# Duplicated records showing up when i ran sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats with same index_id,partition_number,index_depth and level but diff frag ¿why?

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: image_screen]

I'm getting the next case. Using "sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats" for an specific, DB and table i'm obtaining duplicated rows with different fragmentation in the same partition,index_id,index_level and depth... ¿somebody knows what is the reason? and what i ve to do if i want to obtain only the one fragmentation for an specific partition?

the query im using for is the next:

```
SELECT * from sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (DB_ID(N'DB_Name') ,OBJECT_ID(N'Table_Name'), 1, NULL , 'LIMITED')
WHERE [alloc_unit_type_desc] = 'IN_ROW_DATA'
```

Comment: Are you concurrently running an online index rebuild? Wonder if that might cause both "new" and "old" to appear for the duration of the operation

Comment: Ei Martin, this is not the point, i'm only scanning without running any online index rebuild, and scanning this table for example with this specific query i get "repeat" elements with the same index_level in the same partition_number and index_id. ¿Why it happens? what is the real difference between the row 3 and 4 for example? 

thank you!